# Программное управление Tor в Windows

Tags: c#, windows, tor

Ищу способ сменить выходную ноду тора программно из c#. Ну и было бы здорово узнать как указать определенные страны выходной ноды программно, не через редактирование файла torrc.

Comment: Вам сменить только выходную? Или полностью перестроить цепочку?

Comment: Нашел управление через telnet. Но у меня телнет не подключается к 127.0.0.1:9050. Просто вечно висит. 
http://dimio.org/tor-newnym-avtomaticheskaya-smena-ip-v-tor.html

Может можно как-то управлять через опции exe?
Или кто-нибудь подскажет, что делать с телнетом? 
Я запустил службу указав файл torrc в котором прописан ControlPort 9050. telnet по прежнему не может завершить подключение. Если отключить службу - телнет говорит мол разорвано соединение. Вот только соединение он так и не установил.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Не принципиально, главное ip поменять, а там что проще будет.

Comment: Да, все правильно, нужно через Control Port работать. Но почему у вас нет коннекта - не знаю...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вот тут http://www.cyberforum.ru/internet-security/thread1292943.html
высказывается мнение, что 127.0.0.1 - локалхост, т.е. я пытаюсь через телнет подключиться к самому себе. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Не в этом проблема, что прокси, что ControlPort будут на той машине, на которой запущен TOR

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вообщем, как я понял, телнет все таки соединяется. Но соединение пропадет после ввода 2х любых символов и меня выкидывает из телнет обратно в cmd.

Comment: Потому что надо не любые два вводить, а в соответствии с протоколом.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да я уже что-только не пробовал туда вбивать. и команды от телнета (st). И AUTOFICATE. только ввожу 2 символ и сразу вылет. При этом символы не показываются. Просто пустые поля.
Если запускаю сначала просто телнет и в нем конекчусь через open. То такой же вылет, но еще и текст накладывается друг на дружку. Может быть у меня сам клиент кривой?

Comment: А вы читали спецификацию Tor Control Protocol?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов листал, но у меня не настолько хорошо с английским, что бы найти там решение мой проблемы.